# AlarmManager is not starting my background Service anymore if application gets killed ( Taskmanager - exit application )

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

Friends,

i have an Activity that sets up an AlarmManager. The Alarmmanager should call a backgroundservice in a certain timeperiod. Everything works perfect untill i kill the application with the Android Taskmanager - exit application. Then nothing happens anymore.
Is there any way to avoid loosing the Alarms???

Heres my Activity to set up the Alarm

```
PendingIntent pi;
AlarmManager mgr;
mgr=(AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(DataCollectionActivity.this, HUJIDataCollectionService.class);
pi = PendingIntent.getService(DataCollectionActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
mgr.cancel(pi);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , 1* 60* 1000, pi);
```

The service is just a regular Activity extends Service,

and here my manifest file

```
<service android:name=".services.HUJIDataCollectionService" android:process=":remote"/>   
<activity android:name=".activities.DataCollectionActivity"  
           android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.sheep.activities.DataCollectionActivity" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works perfect untill i kill the application with the Android Taskmanager - exit application. Then nothing happens anymore.

This definitely happens on Android 2.1 and earlier. A related effect (preventing broadcasts from being received) affects Android 3.1+.

> Is there any way to avoid loosing the Alarms???

Don't kill the application with a task killer or force-stop from within Settings.